# Why I am unable to join separate meshes together?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view

I downloaded a Sims 3 3D model mesh to make custom clothes for the game Sims 3.  but I noticed all the parts of the models body were separated including the eyes, head, and feet. So I tried to merge all the separated meshes together by pressing the join key but  I got the error no mesh data to join.  I don't why or  how to solve this issue and its really makes things harder for me. If you know a solution to this problem,  please let me know.
I must be doing something wrong.  Here is the blend file of the model:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/jpajin1epe8bvko/myobjectfile.blend

[image]

Comment: I have just successfully joined all your character meshes into one, so I don't know what you are talking about. How are you joining them? What hot keys are you pressing? What objects have you selected? Which object is the active one?

Comment: I pressed on the join button in the edit section in the tools tab.

Comment: I also tried to the hotkey ctrl+J to join but I still got the error. No mesh data to join.   Can you explain to me how you did it exactly by showing a picture or video?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the issue.

Comment: All I had to do was press shift to join the meshes together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an active object to join meshes together (a selected object that other meshes are being joined TO).

Comment: Please mark the question as solved with your solution then.